# Converting datetime string values to integers alters month string?

Tags: python, datetime, types, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to use `datetime` and then converting that to unix time so that I can push it into a url as a variable. Getting an odd error I didn't get when I originally created this code.

```
now = datetime.now()
date_time_d = now.strftime("%d")
date_time_m = now.strftime("%m")
date_time_y = now.strftime("%Y")
date_time_h = now.strftime("%hr")
date_time = datetime(int(date_time_y), int(date_time_m), int(date_time_d), int(date_time_h), 00, 00) - timedelta(hours=12)

#Convert datetime to unix for URL (must round to avoid decimals)
unix_time = round(time.mktime(date_time.timetuple()))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Julr'
```

Tried converting `datetime` variables with `int(float(x))` but also did not work.

Comment: Why do you have `r` after `%h`? Is that a typo?

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with the month string?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this by parsing strings instead of using the built-in attributes to get the day, month, year, etc. as integers?

Comment: `now.year, now.month, now.day`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like it's trying to convert a string to an integer. I'd make a list of the months (though I'd put nothing/something random in the first slot since that's slot 0) and convert the month string into its assigned slot on the list.

Comment: When I print out date_time_m = now.strftime("%m"), it returns 07 as a string.